# Is it possible to get frequency from an audio without play it?

Tags: ios, audio, audiokit

My iOS project requires to retrieve some audio data (i.e. frequency , decibel) from an audio file.

By using AudioKit framework, I can get those data from the microphone by use AKFrequencyTracker, however, I am struggling on how to get the frequency straight away from the audio file without playing it. Because I need those data to plot some graphs (i.e. frequency vs. time, etc)

PS: I'm saving the record as an m4a format at the moment. (the format is optional)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a tad lost on your question - AKFrequencyTracker has a `frequency` variable

Comment: @ impression7vx Thanks for your reply. My question is can I possible to get frequency data from an audio file without playing it? Or I have to get the data while playing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/fast_fourier_transforms) FFT API's to get the frequency information from an audio file.

Here is a useful library to understand vDSP API usage.

https://github.com/tomer8007/real-time-audio-fft